# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so'

Tags: php, postgresql, macos, symfony

I have an application in symfony using doctrine and PGSQL.

I'm using MacOsx BigSur.

When I run my projet I have this error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so'
```

I have install php@7.3 with `brew install php@7.3`

In the /etc/php.ini I added the line `extension=pgsql.so` of the end of file.

I have restart my services with: `brew services restart php@7.3`

When I run php -v I have a warning : `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so'`

And when I run my symfony application I have this error:

```
In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 79:
                                                          
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  
                                                          

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                         
  could not find driver
```

How can I install pgsql to run my application correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this command line but it's obsolete

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my problem I have installed php@7.3 with brew

```
brew install php@7.3
```

After that you need to do:

```
echo ‘export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH”’ >> ~/.profile
echo ‘export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH”’ >> ~/.profile
```

You can run again and that's work.